# htaccess allow www process access to folder, deny everything else

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am building a site that uses php to insert user data into pages.
I have 3 folders

- public_html
- scripts
- user_data

In the public_html folder there are .php files that insert files from user_data into the page.

How can I prevent the access to the files in the scripts and user_data folder ?

All the user_data files have .inc extensions. If I modify the .htaccess file with the following rule the phpscript itself is not allowed to read the data.

```
<Files ~ "\.inc$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Is there a way to enforce this with .htaccess or should I write a check in php to see if the right user is logged in to display this page ?

Comment: are you using linux servers?

Comment: If you set your DocumentRoot to `public_html` then scripts folder is anyway out of reach for web traffic.

Comment: yes I am on a linux server.
If I set the documentRoot to public_html the scripts can not be read.
I tried that first but then I can not login. After reversing the documentRoot to the original I could login again.